# MariaDB: Should I configure the db-server using "/etc/my.cnf" or a file in "/etc/my.cnf.d"?

Tags: sql, mariadb, database-administration

I am trying to configure MariaDB on a machine with Fedora 37: Workstation as its operating system.

I expected to use `/etc/my.cnf` to configure the ports and such, however, the file contained an include to the directory `/etc/my.cnf.d`. I am confused as to why it has `.d` as an extension, from computer science class I remember paths ending in .d being like header files, but dependencies instead for C++ programs.

So what I would like to know is this:
Am I able to configure MariaDB using `/etc/my.cnf`, and can I also use the `mariadb-server.cnf` file in the `/etc/my.cnf.d` directory.

If I can use both, then is it correct to assume that any settings set in `/etc/my.cnf` will override other configurations placed inside the `/etc/my.cnf.d` directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### While `/etc/my.cnf` is the main config file, `/etc/my.cnf.d` is a directory for additional MySQL config files.

With regards to this question:

> “I am confused as to why it has .d as an extension, from computer science class I remember paths ending in .d being like header files, but dependencies instead for C++ programs.”

All the `.d` stands for is `d`irectory. That’s it.

It’s just a different way of organizing config files. Nothing really deep or technical. And if you ask me, it is not needed for a MySQL install but I’m not a MariaDB developer who decided to create this functionality. So… hey! Onto the core details.

> “If I can use both, then is it correct to assume that any settings set in `/etc/my.cnf` will override other configurations placed inside the `/etc/my.cnf.d` directory?”

Nope. The exact opposite: `/etc/my.cnf` gets loaded first and the configs in `/etc/my.cnf.d` gets loaded afterwards. Details below.

While `/etc/my.cnf` is the main config file, `/etc/my.cnf.d` is a config directory. Meaning a directory that might contain multiple config files.

As [the official MariaDB docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/#including-option-file-directories) explain:

> ### Including Option File Directories
>
> It is also possible to include all option files in a directory from another option file. For example, to include all option files in /etc/my.cnf.d/, an option file could contain:
>
> ```
> [mariadb]
> ...
> !includedir /etc/my.cnf.d/
> ```

That `!includedir` config option will load config files from the `/etc/my.cnf.d/` directory. Typically after the main config in `/etc/my.cnf` loaded.

The reality is you can just make all of the changes you want in the main `/etc/my.cnf` file but the `/etc/my.cnf.d` directory can contain config options you wish to manage separately.

Honestly, I have never understood the benefit for MySQL. But — for example — in Apache there is a similar directory called `/etc/httpd/conf.d` and that is where I would drop specific config files that change depending on server and location.

But for MySQL (or MariaDB) I just make all of my changes in the main `/etc/my.cnf` config file.

I mean, maybe you could break out all of the InnoDB config options and set them in a config file called `/etc/my.cnf.d/innodb.cnf` and load that as needed. But each time I think about the benefits of doing something like that, it still seems like an excessively fragmented method of config management.

In the end, you need to look at `/etc/my.cnf.d/` as a convenience method of managing config files. If you don’t need it, don’t use it.

Comment: I just wanted to note that this is obviously a far more thorough answer than the generic style answers commonly authored. And that the quality of your published answer hasn't went unnoticed. This answer was very helpful, it was an answer that most certainly endowed me with a deeper understanding of the topic, therefore; I sincerely thank you.